# How to tune xrdp + remmina for best performance

Tags: 18.04, xrdp, remmina

Starting with 18.04 on both ends I want to access my remote machine via RDP.

I have verified that the client using remmina works very fast using `GFX RFX` colour depth connecting to a Windows 10 RDP server. Please note that neither of `GFX AVC` variants works as there seems that libfreerdp doesn't come prebuilt with their support on 18.04 (remmina installed by apt, not manually from their repo).

When I connect to an Ubuntu 18.04 server running xrdp, performance is not nearly the same: the entire experience is laggy, especially at resolutions above full HD. It is clearly not using the advanced codecs.

I tried installing Remmina from their repo to test the AVC depths, but the only thing that changes is removing the AVC depths from the list altogether so now I can't even select them (previously they just didn't work). Apt didn't touch the libfreerdp libraries though when I upgraded Remmina from their repo.

How can I set up my systems such that I will have good performance?

Comment: In the mean time I switched to nomachine. Seems to work.

Comment: Another update: I'm currently using spice (linux guests) and RDP (windows guests), but spice is only usable when used on local machine. Over LAN or WAN even, it becomes too laggy